# How to send data from JQuery Ajax to ASP.NET page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using `JQuery Ajax` to send a data from one domain to an `ASP.NET` page that is in another domain. I'm able to get the response back from `ASP.NET` page but I'm not able to send the data from `JQuery Ajax`. Here is my code:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://somewebsite/dbd/leap.aspx',
            data: '{ year: "' + $('#txtYear').val() + '"}',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("inside sucess");
                console.log("result: " + result);
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });
```

I can reach `leap.aspx` page. Note `http://somewebsite` is just a placeholder.

`leap.aspx` has the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="leap.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%=output %>
```

`leap.aspx.cs` has the following: Note I'm using `Request.Params["year"]` to get the value of year passed by `Ajax` call but no luck.

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
public string output = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Request.Params["callback"] != null)
    {
        output = Request.Params["callback"] + "('" + GetData(Request.Params["year"]) + "')";
    } 
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string GetData(string year)
{  
return "From outer space! " + year;
}
```

}

When I run this code, in console I see

> "result: From outer space!"

but I do not see the data sent for year by `Ajax`.  I'm using `JSONP` because I'm making a cross-domain request to get around Same Origin Policy. I'm not getting any error.  I'm just not getting the getting the value of year returned from `ASP.NET` page.

How do I get the year?

Comment: if the data is {year: "2001"} I think in a lot of cases you want the .json to have quotes around the key and the value... does changing the format of your `data: ` to {"year": "2001"} fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the data setting to remove the quotes like this:

```
data: { year: $('#txtYear').val() },
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Changing to data: { year: "' + $('#txtYear').val() + '"} fixed the issue. I'm getting year back now.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with a pre-defined object and [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/sep/07/using-jquery-to-post-form-data-to-an-aspnet-asmx-ajax-web-service) helped me.